# Why alien command gives error like this "Can't locate object method "new"?

Tags: oracle11g, ubuntu-14.04, alien

I am trying to install oracle xe 11g locally on ubuntu 14.04.
First I need to convert rpm package to deb version.
When I used alien command

```
sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

I get following error.

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Alien::Package::Rpm" at /usr/bin/alien line 437.
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled and installed alien and it worked.

```
sudo apt-get remove alien
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Thanks anyway